# Flask logging 2.7

Tags: python-2.7, flask

I am having some troubles setting the Flask logger. I would like to have my custom logs and flask log in the same file.

I tried this :

```
formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler = RotatingFileHandler('test.log', maxBytes=10000000, backupCount=5)
handler.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
application.logger.addHandler(handler)
application.logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

but only my logs are saved into the test.log file. What am I doing wrong?

I am using python 2.7 and Flask 0.10.1.

Comment: What did you expect to happen instead?

Comment: That all logs of my app ( i.e. flask logs and mine ) were logged in the the test.log file. What happens is, my logs are in the test.log file whereas flask logs are int he stdout.

Comment: Then attach to the root logger instead of the app logger.

Comment: how? Probably, I don't know how to do that..

Comment: `import logging`, `logging.getLogger()` gets you the root logger object.